# need to fetch the url/src of image

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to retrieve the src of an img in the "the_content" and also need to print it in the last anchor as you can see in the code below. I tried almost everything from my knowledge and also from the internet but no luck. plz help.
I removed everything that I tried and put the clean code so that you guys could easily understand it.

```
<?php query_posts('cat=7');?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="impresna  zoom-img" id="zoom-img">
        <?php the_content();  // it contain images>
        <span class="main"><span class="emboss">MARCA - SP</span><?php the_date(); ?>

            <a class="lb_gallery" href="need to print url of image here">+ZOOM</a></span>
            <br clear="all" />
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: don't use `query_posts` its very bad for loading speed. Use `WP_Query` see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to function.php

```
function get_first_image_url ($post_ID) {
 global $wpdb;
 $default_image = "http://example.com/image_default.jpg";   //Defines a default image
 $post = get_post($post_ID);
 $first_img = '';
 ob_start();
 ob_end_clean();
 $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
 $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

 if(empty($first_img))
 { 
    $first_img = $default_image;
 }
 return $first_img; }
```

To retrieve the src of an img :

```
<a class="lb_gallery" href="<?php echo get_first_image_url ($post->ID); ?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to parse the string returned from `the_content()` to extract the `img` tag. Here are a number of [ways to parse HTML in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php). For example, with DOM it will be something like this:

```
<?php
$content = get_the_content();
echo $content;
$last_src = '';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
if($dom->loadHTML($content))
{
    $imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    if($imgs->length > 0)
    {
        $last_img = $imgs->item($imgs->length - 1);
        if($last_img)
            $last_src = $last_img->getAttribute('src');
    }
}
?>
<a class="lb_gallery" href="<?php echo htmlentities($last_src); ?>">
```

Comment: `the_content` itself already does echo. You need `get_the_content`

Comment: @janw, Thanks. I don't do WordPress.